# Sass/Compass compressed output still not enough for Google Pagespeed Insights

Tags: css, sass, minify, pagespeed, compass-sass

I generate my css file using Sass/Compass (scss style) with the "compressed" outputstyle:

```
compass watch --output-style compressed
```

This way it is minified and without comments, etc. 
However, Google Pagespeed Insights still tells me that I can win size with minifying.

Probably I could win some space, but since it's a generated file, I do not want to keep manually minifying it.

Is the Compass outputstyle known to not be efficient? Is there something else I need to look at, that can be done dynamically with the generated css file?

Comment: What pre-processor are you using to handle your sass? Your options may vary depending on which one.

Comment: You mean the sass filetype? That's scss. If not, please clarify your question. I edited my question with more detail info.

Comment: That should generate the smallest possible css, it's all one line, no spaces. Did you check the generated files? Also pagespeed isn't perfect, did you try yslow as well?

Comment: @cimmanon: I think the question about efficiency is a plausible question, and I simply request experience with it. I do not quite get the minus one on my question nor the assumption that I did not check sass issues.

Comment: @Valentin It is correctly compressed so no issue there. Maybe indeed pagespeed is lacking, could very well be. Had not checked out yslow, have now. Gives me grade A on css minify. So it's just Pagespeed giving me unnecessairy hard time then?

Comment: @DennisPoort Yes, most likely acting up, I've had similar issues with it. Pagespeed will also show you what the gain from further compressing your CSS will be. If it's like 1-2k don't even bother with it, it won't matter in production. My motto is to use these tools to get a general idea if there are major problems with my sites but I won't waste 99% effort to gain 1% performance improvement. Take everything with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @Valentin Ok cool thanks for sharing your insights! Thing is that performance is nowadays not the only issue. The analytics score for mobile/desktop becomes part of the sale. :/

Answer (score 1):

It matters for the first bite load, then it will get cached anyways, however you can still optimize your Css by removing unnecessary code, what i mean here is code that will never been used in your page.
Another optimization technique is to reduce nesting levels because nesting inflate the .css file size

Comment: Will put more effort in this. I can optimize indeed. Sometimes I get the message that the css is considered as a blocking script, instead of it not being minified enough, which certainly supports your comment. Even if it's not the answer to the question about actual minifying, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am in the middle of optimising some of my sites, and the only way I can get PageSpeed to give me 100% is to inline the CSS and compress it (using Gulp) during output to my distribution folder. This is along with automatice GZip of files on the server, and compression of both HTML and inline CSS. Also have to defer loading of JavaScript and keep some of that inline (particularly for mobile).

Answer (score 0):

You could install [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) or use [PageSpeed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service). Both are automated tools for optimizing websites based on PageSpeed rules.

Comment: Tried that. The pagespeed insights grade actually lowers when I turn on certain mod_pagespeed settings. At the moment I limit it to removing html whitespace, which seems good.